# Change color cell in UITableView Previously recorded Swift

Tags: swift, uitableview, cell, uicolor

How can I change the color of cells that have been added?

When I change if the cell changes the color that will be added to the UITableView , I need to change the color of the cells in all the TableView .

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell_1") as! TableView_Cell
        let item = self.items[indexPath.row]
        cell.la_view.text = item.list_1
        cell.la_view2.text = item.list_2

    switch sw {
    case 0:
    cell.la_view.textColor = UIColor.green
    cell.la_view2.textColor = UIColor.green

    case 1:
    cell.la_view.textColor = UIColor.white
    cell.la_view2.textColor = UIColor.white

    default:
        print("")
    }
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor(named: "Defeult")

        return cell
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only have two colors, then you can just use a Boolean variable:

```
var colorSwitch = false
```

Then in your `tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {`:

```
if colorSwitch {
    cell.la_view.textColor = //color
    cell.la_view2.textColor = //color
else {
    cell.la_view.textColor = //color
    cell.la_view2.textColor = //color
```

If you have more than one color to change to, you can have an integer value and use the switch case statement you have already.

Comment: If you want all the cells to be changed, just toggle the Boolean and call `tableView.reloadData()` which will refresh the tableView.